# php function array argument manipulation

Tags: php

i am making insert function that takes $table argument and $cols(as array)argument.
it inserts into given table given values:

```
$db->query("insert into $table({$cols[0]},{$cols[1]}) values('{$_POST[{$cols[0]}]}','{$_POST[{$cols[1]}]})");
```

this is all nice except i don't how long array is. how to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you haven't done is escaped the SQL using the correct escaping mechanism.

```
$postCols = $_POST['cols']; 

foreach($postCols as &$col) {
    $col = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($col) . '"';
}

$db->query("insert into $table(" . implode(',', $cols) . ") values(" . implode(',', $postCols . ");
```

Comment: Haha, I've been using C# to much. Completely forgot about the implode function.  Your code is a lot cleaner.

Comment: looks great, just remember to escape the values and wrap them in quotes.  `$escAndQuote = function($x) {return "'" . mysql_real_escape($x) . "'";}; $colVals = array_map($escAndQuote, $_POST['cols']);`

Comment: what does $_POST['cols'] represent?

Comment: @Daniel It looks like you get the POST variables directly, in which case you could change the loop to suit.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use some foreach loops

```
<?php
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (";
  foreach ($cols as $col)
      $sql .= "`$col`,";
  $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
  $sql .= ") VALUES(";
  foreach ($cols as $col)
      $sql .= "'".$_POST[$col]."',";
  $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
  $sql .= ");";

  echo $sql;
?>
```